# Tools or data base tips to show big data information?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, bigdata, business-intelligence

I'm having a problem with an application builded in .net core(c#) and SQL server 2017 with angular js version 1.x (frondend).

The problem is the following we have are very big tables, with millons of records. Only a simple select count in one of theses tables takes to long.  we execute the query directly from the code without passing through any ORM librery, but even without using any ORM the queries take too long.

**I was asking myself ¿if there is another better way to consult these giant tables likes (external tools, another type of database, etc.) since in many cases you need to show reports and see statistics graphs?.**

Comment: If the DB needs that long you can only optimize there: create better indexes, pre-generate the data you need (e.g. every day/hour), ...

Comment: If a count takes a lot of time, it's time to put a DBA there to analyze that database. You are doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible strategy is to use table partitions using a partition function that match your business needs. With this you can split data in table among many files, thus reducing the number of results to scan.

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes) link for detailed info.

Comment: yes thanks, that could be a posibility.If you know another possible solution, it will be welcome. 
I'm looking for a solution with the least possible impact on the server code.

Comment: @lucianocba Going this way there are not changes in your table structures neither need to modify code, table partition is handled transparently by the database server.

Comment: we optimize the indexes and queries, but still takes a long time when the report that we want to generate analyzes not only one, in same cases we need to do querys with 2 or 3,4 of these giant tables.

Comment: I will consider your solution very seriously and propose it

Answer (score 1):

OLTP databases like SQL Server are not designed for handling OLAP (aggregate) queries in the real time in case of large datasets. Typical workarounds are:

- limit number of aggregated rows with extra WHERE conditions, and add indexes for these columns. This is usually is possible with historic data like orders, events log etc - show reports only for last month or year.
- use materialized views and use it for reports that doesn't need much detalization
- configure slave read-only instance of SQL Server, possibly add columnstore indexes, and use it for OLAP queries.
- replicate your SQL Server data to specialized (possibly, distributed) analytical database that can handle OLAP queries in the real-time (like Amazon Redshift, Vertica, MongoDb, ElasticSearch, Yandex ClickHouse etc)

If reports can be configured by end users ensure that your ROLAP-like engine produces efficient SQL GROUP BY queries.

Comment: Hello, the database is a instance of azure, the size of the database is 200GB now

Comment: @lucianocba in case of Azure you can also check their Azure SQL Data Warehouse service, it might be useful in some cases - everything depends on your concrete use-case specifics.